# Get the closest point on a surface - Maya - Python

Tags: python, maya

Could someone help me?
How can I get the closest point on a surface form a locator in Maya using python OpenMaya?
I was trying to use constraints but it has some snap that is not good for me.
I would like to get the closest point, not the closest vertex. I want to get the nearest position from a locator even if it is at the center of a polygon. :)

thanks a lot!!!

Comment: get the closest vertex. Loop over polygons sharing the vertex and compute closest point for each polygon and choose the closest one

Comment: thanks @JanStránský, I didnt understand what you meant, but I will try to figure out.

Comment: I meant that having the closes vertex is already a good starting point. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for a better discussion

Comment: I cant post an image because I have less than 10 reputations.. :/

Comment: I even made the image explainning better, but cant post.

Comment: "minimal reproducible example" in this case is the **code** you have tried already - finding the closest vertex on some "toy" mesh (e.g. a cube). Then the problem can be much more easily understood and possibly solve.

Comment: I have almost nothing.. I just have this:
import maya.OpenMaya as om

surfaceObj = "pSphere1"
lct = "locator1"

surfaceObj_pos = cmds.getAttr("surfaceObj.translate")

Comment: sorry for the very beginner question man.. :/

Comment: I don't know OpenMaya so I cannot help more, my first comment is a general approach..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the simplest way would be to use a "closestPointOnSurface" node. Connect your surface to the node and the position of your locator to the "In Position", then you can get the result from the node. But that would be without OpenMaya. If you want to use OpenMaya, you could try to use a ray intersect on the mesh.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OpenMaya.MFnMesh.getClosestPoint`

Check out [the docs here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2018/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_fn_mesh_html).

This example should get you started:
http://discourse.techart.online/t/using-getcloserpoint-from-mayas-python-api/9441/3

Comment: thank you very much, I will look for info to use this function! :)